# Sprechpause bei "Gendergap" - Beispiele für solche Pausen außerhalb des "Genderns"

Tags: pronunciation, gender, spoken-language, gender-neutrality

**Es geht hier nicht um Meinungen oder Einstellungen zur Sinnhaftigkeit!
Mir geht es um eine "technische" Frage, die den Leitlinien der [Meta-Diskussion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/wie-k%C3%B6nnen-wir-den-themenbereich-um-geschlechtergerechte-sprache-objektiv-halten) folgt.**

---

Im Beispiel

> Schüler:Innen (oder anderen Formen der "gendergerechten Sprache")

"sollte" der ':', in der gesprochenen Sprache, durch eine kurze Pause /ʔ/ repräsentiert werden.

Meine Frage ist nun, ob es "vergleichbare" (*) Sprechpausen auch außerhalb dieses Kontextes gibt.

Ich hoffe ich habe meine Frage sinnvoll und verständlich formuliert.

---

(*) Auch hier bitte ich darum, die Formulierung nicht als Diskussionsanlass zu nutzen. "Vergleichbar" fragt hier nicht nach Meinungen, sondern bezieht sich auf "technische" Aspekte des Sprechens.

Comment: Meinst du einen stimmlosen Konsonanten (glottal stop, 'Okina), wie beispielsweise zwischen den ersten beiden Silben in aneinander ? In deutsch gibt's glaube ich kein Wort dafür, obwohl wir es ganz automatisch tun ...

Comment: @a_donda Ja, so ein Beispiel suchte ich, danke. Ist der "stimmlose Konsonant / glottal stop" mit der Pause zwischen zwei Wörtern vergleichbar / dasselbe? Ich kenne mich damit nicht aus, deswegen frage ich, ob das rein "technisch" verglichen werden kann.

Comment: Den gibt's in verschiedenen Varianten, am härtesten wohl im englischen Kiezakzent Cockney, am flüssigsten im polynesichen, wo er auch ein Schiftzeichen ist ('Okina). Eine genaue Deifinition für das deutsche gendern habe ich aber auch nicht ...

Comment: Ich denke, im Deutschen ist (abgesehen von dieser Neuschöpfung) der Glottisschlag sonst nur selten bedeutungsunterscheidend, sowohl entsprechend zu *Schülerinnen/Schüler:innen* als auch im Vergleich zu einer Pause zwischen Wörtern entsprechend *Schüler:innen/Schüler innen*. Es ergibt sich hier eine ungewohnte Mehrdeutigkeit.

Comment: @Bodo: genau das ist ja auch eine übliche Kritik an dieser Form, dass sie ein nur leicht variiertes generisches Femininum etabliert. Aber darum geht es ja hier nicht.

Answer (score 15):

Ich denke, diese „Pause“ wird tatsächlich eher ein Glottisschlag sein, und der ist im Deutschen häufig. In der Aussprache wäre der Unterschied zwischen Schülerinnen und Schüler:Innen also ähnlich dem zwischen einer Spiegelei und einem Spiegelei.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort! Ich muss gestehen, dass ich kurz gebraucht habe(,?) um zu verstehen was *eine* Spiegelei ist.

Comment: Glottisschlag, danke ! Auch (festhalten) Stimmritzenverschlusslaut :-)

Comment: @choXer, das Beispiel habe ich gerade dem Wikipedia-Artikel entnommen.

Comment: @a_donda, ich habe „glottal stop“ gegoogelt :)

Comment: @CarstenS Welchem genau? Bei "geschlechtergerechte Sprache" hab ich das nicht gesehen. Aber ich verstehe den "Hinweis" ;)

Comment: @choXer, so war das nicht gemeint. Ich wollte nur sagen, dass Spiegelei nicht meine Kreativität war, sondern ein Beispiel aus https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottaler_Plosiv, wo ich gelandet war, als ich nachgeschlagen habe, wie ein "glottal stop" auf deutsch heißt.

Comment: Bei Spiegelei gibt es allerdings auch noch einen Unterschied in der Betonung, wenn ich mich nicht täusche. Aber es gibt sicher zahlreiche andere Beispiele.

Answer (score 4):

Ein Minimalpaar wäre "Kita Amerikaweg, Kita am Erikaweg". Der Glottisverschluß bzw. die Sprechpause ist bedeutungsentscheidend,
andere Unterschiede (Vokalqualität, Vokalquantität, Stimmhaftigkeit, Betonung, etc.) gibt es nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Weitere Beispiele, wo der Glottisverschlusslaut im Deutschen ganz natürlich vorkommt (ich verwende hier Apostroph (') als Zeichen für diesen Laut):

- ver'ursachen
- The'ater
- be'urlauben
- be'urkunden
- be'enden
- ver'enden
- ver'edeln
- Not'aufnahme
- Tee'ei
- Käse'omelette
- A'a machen (Kinderausdruck für defäkieren)

Bei manchen Wörtern ist das Glottisverschluss nur sehr schwach ausgeprägt. "Theater" könnte man wohl auch ohne Glottisverschluss sprechen, ohne damit groß aufzufallen. Bei Not'aufnahme wäre wohl auch eine glatte Aussprache ("No-taufnahme") möglich, aber ganz standardmäßig wär's wohl schon mit Glottisverschluss. Ähnlich bei Käseomelette. Je schneller man diese Wörter spricht, desto eher geht der Glottisverschluss in der Praxis auch mal verloren. Bei sehr sauberer Bühnenaussprache würde man ihn aber deutlich hören.

Darüberhinaus steht Glottisverschluss stets vor Vokal am Wortanfang:

- 'Aachen
- 'Urlaub
- 'Essen
- 'Elch
- 'Uhrmacher
- 'Ofensetzer

Das merkt man natürlich nur, wenn das Wort in einer Satzverbindung steht. Man sagt nicht "dem_Ofensetzer" (verbunden) sondern eben "dem 'Ofensetzer" (mit Glottisverschluss).

Fazit: Der Glottisverschluss (der nun auch für *Mitarbeiter*innen* vorgeschlagen wird), ist in der normalen Aussprache des Deutschen wohlbekannt.

Comment: Kommt darauf an, wo. In der normalen Aussprache des Deutschen hier in der Schweiz ist der Glottisschlag ungebräuchlich. Deutsch ist nicht überall gleich.

Comment: Im Deutschen gibt es keinen Glottisverschlusslaut (außer vielleicht in der sogenannten Bühnensprache). Die hier aufgeführten Wörter werden mit intervokalischem Hiatus ausgesprochen. Nicht das gleiche!

Comment: @fdb: Wir benutzen ihn automatisch, wir schreiben ihn nur nicht. Zum Vergleich hawai'ianisch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lb1hTLMXNHA. Die Vokale sind genau wie im deutschen und beginnen mit dem Verschlußlaut der in polynesischen Sprachen eben ein eigenes Schriftzeichen ist. 'Ein 'intervokalischer Hiatus 'am Wort'anfang 'ist 'eigentlich 'ein Widerspruch 'in sich. Be'achte das Fehlen des 'Okinas bei Hiatus.

Answer (score 3):

Zwei gute Beispiele, die verdeutlichen, weshalb der Glotisschlag (oder die Sprechpause) bei manchen Worten nötig ist um den Sinn zu verstehen:

ver'eisen statt verreisen.
be'inhalten statt Bein halten.

Comment: Das zweite Beispiel bedürfte einer tieferen Diskussion.

Answer (score 2):

Ein Beispiel, das häufig in humoristischer Weise gebraucht wird, ist das Wort "Urinstinkt". Ohne die Pause würde man es als "Urin stinkt" aussprechen. Dasselbe gilt für folgende Wörter:

- Fahrspurende *(hat ausnahmsweise nichts mit einem entgendernden Suffix zu tun)*
- Stockente *(hat nichts mit "stockend" zu tun)*
- Staubecken *(geht es hier um staubige Ecken oder um ein Becken, in dem etwas gestaut wird?)*
- Hähncheninnenbrustfilet *(falsch wäre hier die Schreibweise "Hähnchen*innenbrustfilet")*

Answer (score 2):

Eine kurze Pause (eine Zäsur) und /ʔ/ (ein Glottisschlag) sind nicht dasselbe!

#### Zäsur (Sprechpause)

Sprechen Sie diese Wörter aus:

> Krepppapier, Fetttropfen, norddeutsch, Dämmmaterial

In keinem dieser Wörter kommt ein Glottisschlag vor, aber in jedem gibt es an jener Stelle, an der zwei gleiche Konsonanten getrennt voneinander gesprochen werden müssen, eine kleine Zäsur, also eine kurze Sprechpause.

#### Glottisschlag

Wenn man ein Wort ausspricht, das mit dem Vokal A beginnen sollte (»Apfel«, »arbeiten«), entsteht fast immer ein Glottisschlag vor dem Vokal A. Dieser Laut gilt in vielen Sprachen als eigenständiger Vokal und hat in der arabischen Schrift auch einen eigenen Buchstaben (das Hamza; alleinstehende Form: »ء«). In der lateinischen Schrift gibt es aber keinen Buchstaben für diesen Laut, daher wird dieser Konsonant in der deutschen Sprache zwar relativ häufig ausgesprochen, aber niemals geschrieben. Und weil er niemals geschrieben wird, wird er von vielen Menschen auch nicht bewusst wahrgenommen.

In der IPA-Lautschrift wird dieser Konsonant mit dem Zeichen [ʔ] wiedergegeben. Dieses Zeichen sieht einem Fragezeichen (»?«) zwar ähnlich, ist aber ein anderes Zeichen. (Hier direkt nebeneinander: ?ʔ)

Fast alle deutschen Wörter, die mit einem A als ersten Buchstaben geschrieben werden, werden in Wahrheit mit diesem Konsonanten am Anfang ausgesprochen. In mehrsilbigen Wörtern kommt dieser Konsonant häufig dann am Beginn einer Silbe vor, wenn eine Silbe mit einem Vokal endet und die nächste (zumindest in der geschriebenen Form) mit einem Vokal beginnt:

> beachten = beʔachten
> Theater = Theʔater
> Oase = ʔoʔase
> vereinen = verʔeinen (beachte, dass "er" in "ver-" fast wie "ea" besprochen wird und daher am Ende einen gesprochenen Vokal hat)

Aber auch wenn die vordere Silbe in einem Verschlusslaut endet, beginnt die nächste häufig mit einem Glottischlag:

> Hebamme = Hebʔamme

Interessant ist auch, dass der Glottisschlag in Österreich und der Schweiz wesentlich unauffälliger gemacht wird und sehr oft komplett weggelassen wird, so dass vieles von dem, was hier gesagt wird, hauptsächlich für nördlichere Regionen gilt.

#### Schüler:innen

Vergleiche:

> 1. Liebe **Schüler:innen,** ich darf euch recht herzlich im neuen Schuljahr begrüßen.
> 2. Lasst uns zwei konzentrische Kreise bilden: Die Lehrer stehen außen und die **Schüler innen.**

Die beiden fett hervorgehobenen Ausschnitte hören sich für mich ziemlich gleich an. Tatsächlich ist es so, dass das alleinstehende Wort *»innen«* mit einem Glottisschlag am Beginn gesprochen wird. Der Glottisschlag in  *»Schüler:innen«* signalisiert also eigentlich nur, dass die Lautfolge, die der Buchstabenfolge *»innen«* entspricht, als eigenständige Einheit exisitert. Ob diese eigenständige Einheit ein völlig autonomes Wort, oder ein Teil von *»Schüler:innen«* ist, macht keinen Unterschied.

Es gibt an der Stelle des Doppelpunktes aber nicht nur den Glottisschlag, sondern zusätzlich auch eine kurze Zäsur, so wie zwischen *»nord«* und *»deutsch«* in *»norddeutsch«.* Aber Zäsuren im Wortinneren haben nicht viel zu bedeuten, wie die Beispiele ganz am Beginn meiner Antwort belegen. Im vorliegenden Fall ist die Zäsur eine Folge des Einfügens des Glottisschlags.

---

**Zusatzinfo (nicht mehr Teil der eigentlichen Antwort)**

Der lateinische Buchstabe A entstand aus dem phönizischen Zeichen , das den Namen *ʔalf* trägt. In seiner Urform sah es so ähnlich aus wie ∀, jedoch ging der Querstrich auf beiden Seiten über die Schenkel hinaus, so wie in . Dieses Zeichen sollte den Schädel eines Rindes samt Hörnern und Ohren darstellen, und der Laut, den dieses Zeichen darstellte, war ein Glottisschlag, denn das war der erste Laut des phönizischen Wortes für Rind: ʔalef.

Die phönizische Sprache hatte ganz klare Regeln dafür, welche Vokale vor und nach welchen Konsonanten kommen müssen, ähnlich wie in der hebräischen Sprache, und daher war es gar nicht notwendig, Vokale schriftlich wiederzugeben. Wenn man Phönizisch kann, und die Konsonantenfolge vor sich sieht, ist sonnenklar, welche Vokale dazwischen gesprochen werden müssen. Daher enthielt die phönizische Schrift ausschließlich Zeichen für Konsonanten, und dasselbe ist aus demselben Grund auch heute noch bei der hebräischen Schrift der Fall. (Solche Schriftsysteme bezeichnet man daher auch nicht als *Alphabet* sondern als *Abdschad* oder *Abjad*.)

Aber als man dann auch im antiken römischen Reich begann Schrift zu verwenden, adaptierte man die phönizische Schrift. (Diese Darstellung ist verkürzt, weil die koptische und die griechische Schrift bei der Entwicklung auch eine wichtige Rolle spielte, aber das würde den Ramen dieses Textes sprengen.)

Allerdings gab es in der lateinischen Sprache keine strengen Regeln, die es ermöglichten, aus den Konsonanten direkt auf die Vokale zu schließen. Daher brauchte man für die lateinische Sprache auch Schriftzeichen für Vokale. Und weil der Glottisschlag in der lateinischen Sprache vermutlich gar nicht verwendet wurde, aber in phönizischen Worten auf den Glottisschlag praktisch immer der Vokal A folgte, verwendeten die alten Römer das Zeichen ʔalf für den Vokal A.

Und so entstand nicht nur der Buchstabe A, sondern so verschwand auch der Buchstabe, der ursprünglich verwendet wurde, um den Glottisschlag niederzuschreiben.

Answer (score 0):

Da es sich bei dem "Gender-Gap" um eine Art Neologismus handelt, lohnt es sich wohl eher, bei den Fremdwörtern, und dann vor allem bei den zusammengesetzten Fremdwörtern nachzuschauen, die ohne eine deutlich hörbare Silbentrennung im Deutschen anders als gewünscht ausgesprochen würden. Beispiele dafür wären z.B.

- Koedukation
- Aberration
- bilateral

wären Beispiele dafür.

Ich höre übrigens beim Gender Gap keinen Glottisschlag (außer, wenn er wirklich überbetont wird), sondern nur eine kurze Pause.

Comment: Das Beispiel *bilateral* kann ich nicht nachvollziehen, was ist da außer einem langen *i* bemerkenswert?

Answer (score -1):

Ein wichtiges Beispiel, bei dem die Endung durch ein tatsächlich unterscheidbares Wort ersetzt und zur Hervorhebung getrennt wurde ist das scherzhafte *Poliz-Ei* im Gegensatz zu der *Poliz-ei*. Fraglich ist, ob dieses Wortspiel einen historischen Hintergrund hat (vgl. lateinisch *ius* "Gesetz" usw.). Man könnte ferner *Poly-Zysten* unterscheiden, um ein weiteres Unterscheidungskriterium einzuführen, falls ein medizinischer Notfall vorliegt, doch ist dies kein Fachbegriff und wäre dennoch anhand des Vokals zu erkennen. *Poliz-* ist an sich natürlich kein ei-genständiges Wort. Also hat die Sprachpolizei sicherlich kein Verständnis für dieses Beispiel.

> Meine Frage ist nun, ob es "vergleichbare" (*) Sprechpausen auch außerhalb dieses Kontextes gibt.

Es handelt sich wahrscheinlich nicht mal um eine eine Sprechpause. Es dürfte jedem, der mal eine Sprache gelernt hat, doch nachvollziehbar sein, dass Unsicherheit bei Aussprache, Wortwahl, Formulierung u.s.w. und insbesondere *Registerwechsel* zu Unterbrechung im ... Redefluss führt. Dies weiter auszuführen würde hier zu weit führen: Was ist Betonung, wie geht Akzent. Dass das ggf. zu Hyperkorrektur und betont langen Pausen geführt hat und eben nicht zur Normalisierung eines glottalen Verachlusslautes in der Phonotaktik des standarddeutschen ist bedenklich.

Wenn ich bei *Frau von der, ähhm, Leyen* kurz überlegen muss, wie der Nachname war, ist das ja doch eine Pause, aber halt ein ganz anderer (politisch inkorrekter) Kontext. Ausdrücklich pausiert ist außerdem der running-gag von *How I met – "wait for it ..." – your Mother.

---

Natürlich gab es das schon vorher im entgegengesetzten Fall, um exklusiv feminines Gender der *Schüle'rin*, *Freun-din*, bzw. einfach Mehrzahl der *Freun'de* zu betonen und nicht zu unterdrücken. Dabei wird der glottale Verschlusslaut gegebenfalls *ko-artikuliert*, wird aber nicht phonemisch. Da *r* und *d* stimmhaft sind, wird es kaum zu einem echten Verschluss der Stimmlippen kommen, aber durchaus zu einer hörbaren Anspannung. Im Umkehrschluss ist der glottale Verschluss für eine Pause nicht notwendig, da Lautstärke regelt.

Das erste Beispiel ist markant, da *Schüler* ohne weiteres maskulin ist, es widersinnig wäre, *Schüler-in* zu trennen. Ob die Kombination insbesondere im Plural *Schüler-innen* dennoch nützlich sein mag, bleibt dahingestellt.

Das zweite Beispiel unterscheidet sich bei norddeutscher Auslautverhärtung sowieso vom Singular. Ggf. korreliert die Unterscheidung mit einem überlangen Vokal und erhöhter Lautstärke, aber nur ganz selten begegnet etwas wie *Freund'e* und dann eher als Aphasie.

Entscheident ist, dass Wortrennung wie *Schnel-l-ig-keit* (Duden schreibt *schnel-lig-keit* vor) seine Bewandnis hat, aber unterspezifisch ist. Es ist schlicht nicht mehr erkennbar, ob das Suffix *-lig* oder die Endung *-ig* vorliegt. Wollte man aber den Unterschied betonen, würde man sicherlich die Wortfuge irgendwie hörbar machen wollen und die Silben einzeln betonen. Das eine bedingt das andere.

Soweit die Frage auf den glottalen Verschlusslaut abstellt, also etwa /ˈʃnɛlɪç/ (de.Wiktionary) als [ˈʃnɛlʔɪç-] auszusprechen, werden sich immer Negativbeispiele finden lassen. Das ist eine eher theoretische Frage, die mehr Vorarbeit bedarf.

Dass es (":innen") sich um eine "Sprechpause" handelt(:e) dürfte im Ergebnis richtig sein.

---

> (*) Auch hier bitte ich darum, die Formulierung nicht als Diskussionsanlass zu nutzen.

Das ist im Grunde unmöglich, ohne den Kontext vorher zu diskutieren und hinreichend zu charakterisieren. Sofern das durch eine generelle Ablehnung erfolgt, ist das doch auch schon tendenziös. Deswegen muss eine Antwort sich unbedingt mit *-in, *-innen* auseinandersetzen